# Text File Mapping

Tags: c#, .net, text-parsing

I have a text files that are coming always in the same text format (I do not have the xsd of the text file).

I want to map the data from it to some class.

Is there some standard way to do so, except starting writing string parsers or some complicated REGEXs.

I really do not want to go with text parsers becasue we are several people working on this and it probably take each of us time to understand what the other is doing .

[Example](http://pastebin.com/SEhxuw3L)

Thanks.

Comment: You should post the contents of an example text file, or link to it.

Comment: @Moozhe You are right , I am added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you have a special format you need your own parser** for sure.

If the format is a standard one like **xml, yml, json, csv** etc, the parsing library will be always available in your language.

**UPDATE**

From the sample you provide it seems the format is more like *INI file* but entries are custom. May be you could *extend*  **[NINI](http://nini.sourceforge.net/)**

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Change the format of that file to a standard format like tab delimited or comma separated csv file.
2. Then use  a many libraries that out there to read that files or import it in a database and use an ORM like Entity Framework to read them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot change the incoming file format to something more machine-readable, then you will probably need to write your own custom parser.  The best way to do it would be to create classes to represent and store all of the different kinds of data, using the appropriate data formats for each field (custom enums, DateTime, Version, etc.)

Try to compartmentalize the code.  For example, take these lines here:

```
272 298 9.663 18.665 -90.000 48 0 13 2 10 5 20009 1 2 1 257 "C4207" 0 0 1000 0 0
```

This could be a single class or struct.  Its constructor could accept the above string as a parameter, and each value could be parsed to to different local members.  That same class could have a Save() or ToString() method that converts all the values back to a string if needed.

Then the parent class would simply contain an array of the above structure, based on how many entries are in the file.